# Prevent iPhone from zooming in on `select` in web-app

Tags: javascript, css, html, iphone-web-app

I've got this code:

```
<select>
    <option value="c">Klassen</option>
    <option value="t">Docenten</option>
    <option value="r">Lokalen</option>
    <option value="s">Leerlingen</option>
</select>
```

Running in a full-screen web-app on iPhone.

When selecting something from this list, the iPhone zooms in on the `select`-element. And doesn't zoom back out after selecting something.

How can I prevent this? Or zoom back out?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It is probably because the browser is trying to zoom the area since the font size is less than the threshold, this generally happens in iphone.

Giving a metatag attribute "user-scalable=no" will restrict the user from zooming elsewhere. Since the problem is with **select** element only, try using the following in your css, this hack is originally used for jquery mobile.

HTML :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

CSS:

```
select{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

src: [unzoom after selecting in iphone](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2069)

Comment: If the text is visible (as in my case) it seems that 16px is the minimum before it enables the zoom.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, this line will prevent autoscaling: `$('<meta>', {name: 'viewport',content: 'user-scalable=no'}).appendTo('head');`

Comment: Since when is the text hidden in a select element?? "Will not bring any layout issues"

Comment: var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );

if(iOS) {
 $('element-to-apply-to').css('font-size', '50px');
}

Comment: @Billy A select element on a mobile browser does not render like a desktop web browser. The mobile OS like android/iOS pops out native view to actually select a value. So the font size does not matter at all, this is what I meant. Thanks

Comment: @Billy I mean to say, When the font-size is given a value of 50px, it looks odd on other html elements than a dropdown, which I called layout issue.

Comment: See @martinedwards's answer below where it is revealed that this trick works for anything greater than 16px. So it doesn't have to be a 50px monster.

Comment: tywm. wtf with this apple bs? zooming form inputs, changing style of text phone numbers and etc

Comment: But if you need to allow user-scalable for acessibility issues or any other reason see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483425/prevent-iphone-from-zooming-in-on-select-in-web-app/32884742#32884742

Comment: This hack is working in case of input types. But when i am selecting any value from dropdown (I am using angular's `ui-select`) than it gets zoomed. I tried to increase the font size of lists in dropdown but it didn't worked. Any help?

Comment: @Abbas how could I do this in vanilla JS?

Comment: @Telarian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982228/how-to-add-meta-tag-in-javascript

Comment: Hi, just the meta tag fixed the issue. I didn't need the font-size property at all.

Comment: I was thinking `user-scalable=no` is not working in iOS! does it work?

Answer (score 57):

user-scalable=no is what you need, just so there's actually a definitive answer to this question

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Actually, adding width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 should be enough. I don't believe you need user-scalable with maximum-scale.

Comment: @DanSmart, in at least my case (and I don't know what sets it apart), min/max scale wasn't enough - adding user-scalable=no did make difference.

Comment: This feels like a very heavy-handed approach – I recommend using user-scalable=no with caution. [From Dev.Opera](https://dev.opera.com/articles/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/), "It is also possible to completely turn off zooming, however keep in mind that zooming is an important accessibility feature that is used by a lot of people. Turning it off should therefore only happen when really necessary, such as for certain types of games and applications."

Comment: user-scalable is ignored as of iOS 10.

Comment: When your font is larger than 16px, the browser may zoom out when focusing an input. For me, I only needed to add `minimum-scale=1`, which also preserves the user's possibility to zoom.

Answer (score 40):

**iPhone's will zoom form fields slightly if the text is set to less than 16 pixels**. I'd suggest setting the mobile form field's text to be 16 pixels and then override the size back down for desktop.

The answers saying to disable zoom are unhelpful for accessibility / partially sighted users may still want to zoom on smaller mobiles.

Example:

```
# Mobile first
input, textarea, select {
  font-size: 16px;
}

# Tablet upwards
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: That's good! But what if my text overflows the full width of the select box? What can I do in this case?

Comment: If your starting option message fits on, then that should suffice. As once they have selected an option, even if slightly truncated they will likely remember what it was. But yeah, more of a problem if it says "Please choose a Co..."

Comment: This answer works and seems to offer the least obtrusive method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

This seemed to work for my case in addressing this issue:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
select:focus, textarea:focus, input:focus {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone) by [Christina Arasmo Beymer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004312/christina-arasmo-beymer)

Comment: In my case IOS 7x the old user-scalable was not enough. The above did the trick thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

I am a bit late to the party, but I found a pretty neat workaround that solves this issue only with css manipulation. In my case I couldn't change the font size due to design reasons, and I couldn't disable zooming as well.

Since iPhone's will zoom form fields slightly if the text is set to less than 16 pixels, we can trick the iPhone to think that the font size is 16px and then transform it to our size.

For example, lets take the example when our text is 14px, so it does zoom because it is smaller than 16px. Therefore we can transform the scale, according to 0.875.

In the following example I've added the padding to show how to convert other properties accordingly.

```
.no-zoom {
    font-size: 16px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(0.875);            //  14px / 16px
    padding: 4.57px;                    // 4px / 0.875
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: It's a nasty but also clever hack and I don't like hacks... but in this case it's the best answer on this page and there is no alternative if you have to stop the zoom and still want to keep the design like it is. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The best answer IMHO. The only note - one might have to play with `transform-origin` values (for example, `center` was the most appropriate in my case).

Answer (score 6):

iOS zooms the page to show a larger input field if its font-size is less than 16px.

**only On click of any field, it's zooming the page. so on click, we are making it as 16px and then changed to default value**

below snippet works fine to me and targeted for mobile devices,

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 select:active, input:active,textarea:active{
        font-size: 16px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function DisablePinchZoom() 
{
    $('meta[name=viewport]').attr("content", "");
    $('meta[name=viewport]').attr("content", "width=yourwidth, user-scalable=no");
}

function myFunction() 
{
    $('meta[name=viewport]').attr("content", "width=1047, user-scalable=yes");
}


<select id="cmbYo" onchange="javascript: myFunction();" onclick="javascript: DisablePinchZoom();">
</select>
```

DisablePinchZoom will be fired before the onchange so zoom will be disable at the time the onchange is fired.
On the onchange function, at the end you can restore the initial situation.

Tested on an iPhone 5S

Answer (score 1):

Set all 'select' font size to 16px

select{
font-size: 16px;
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can't do anything about the behavior in isolation.

One thing you can try is keep the page from zooming at all. This is good if your page is designed for the phone.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Another thing you could try is using a JavaScript construct instead of the generic "select" statement. Create a hidden div to show your menu,  process the clicks in javascript.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As answered here: [Disable Auto Zoom in Input "Text" tag - Safari on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone/46254706#46254706)

You can prevent Safari from automatically zooming in on text fields during user input **without** disabling the user’s ability to pinch zoom. Just add `maximum-scale=1` but leave out the user-scale attribute suggested in other answers.

It is a worthwhile option if you have a form in a layer that “floats” around if zoomed, which can cause important UI elements to move off screen.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS to disable Ios' default styling:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

This will also work on other elements that get special styling, like input[type=search].

Answer (score 0):

Been reading for a few hours on this and the best solution is this jquery here.  This also helps with the "next tab" option in iOS Safari.  I have inputs here as well but feel free to remove them or add as you like.  Basically the mousedown fires before the focus event and tricks the browser into thinking its 16px.  In addition, the focusout will trigger on the "next tab" feature and repeat the process.

```
$(function(){
    $('input, select').on("mousedown focusout", function(){
        $('input, select').css('font-size','16px');
    });
    $('input, select').on("focus", function(){
        $('input, select').css('font-size','');
    });
})
```