# iOS input zoom issue

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I am making a responsive page for all mobile browsers. One issue I am running into (particularly for iOS) is that input items zoom in when touched if the `font-size` is less than `16px` - which is a big problem since the mock-up I have for the site uses a smaller `font-size`.

[Disable Auto Zoom in Input "Text" tag - Safari on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone) - the answer here is to set all the input items to 16px.

*and*

[Prevent iPhone from zooming form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064237/prevent-iphone-from-zooming-form) - the answer here is to force "no zoom" on the user - in general this would be a bad UX decision.

Is there some fix out there I can use without forcing the user to not be able to zoom and not have to change the input to some proprietary size (just to conform to iOS)?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9n2Ljqc/2/)

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Don't do this. Why forgo usability for design?

Comment: Maybe use JavaScript/jQuery to try attaching a class to prevent zooming only when a form element is focused? But I have to say, I agree with @evolutionxbox

Comment: @evolutionxbox So it's not possible? I am just trying to adhere to the mock-up I am given as well as give a consistent experience across devices.

Comment: @escapesequence I’ve been there too. The most reliable way to disable zooming is through the viewport meta tag, but I must stress that the loss of usability is not worth it.