# Mobile Safari: zoom out when dropdown list is on blur

Tags: html

On Mobile Safari, when a select list is on focus, the page is automatically zoomed in. It's not zoomed out when the select list is on blur. How do we zoom it back out? Thanks.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: No Dave. It seems to be a bug with iOS version 4.2 which has been fixed in 4.3.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this occurs in later versions of iOS as well.  It annoyed me too so I disabled zoom by using `maximum-scale=1`.  I'm using a jQuery Mobile view anyway so it suited my needs;

eg:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Note that this can be changed dynamically, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2568801/253974. Works to enable/disable zoom for certain jQuery Mobile subpages.

Comment: Discussion on preventing zoom in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone?rq=1 but why is there still no answer how to make mobile Safari zoom out again, instead of preventing zooming in?