# How to disable web page zooming/scaling on Android?

Tags: android, html, scaling, viewport

I have written a small web app to collect some data and store it in a central database. I'm walking around, reading values and typing them into a web site on my Android smartphone. It's just for me, so no public usability concerns apply this time.

Now I want to add a button to increment a reading by one, and I need to be able to push that button several times. But if I do it too fast, the browser recognises a double-tab and scales/zooms into the page.

I have added a viewport header already and played with every value combination I could find on the web. But the page remains scalable. How can I stop that?

Here's a minimal test page that fails for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    font: 16pt sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
This is a test page. It should not be scalable by the user at all. Not with the two-pinger pinch gesture and even less with a double-tap on the text.
</body>
</html>
```

Adding initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 and all sorts of target-whateveritwas-dpi doesn't change a thing. I have restarted the browser (Dolphin HD and the stock browser) and cleared the cache already. I'm on Android 2.2, the phone is an HTC Desire.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I got the same problem on Samsung device and HTC? Meta tags not working..

Comment: This comment poses a very similar question, and the answer was apparently that you have to live with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073396/disable-zoom-on-input-focus-in-android-webpage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a known bug in Android browsers : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11912

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. Accepted, given the low number of other helpful answers.

Comment: "user-scalable=no" has never worked for me, instead I use "user-scalable=0" which seems to work a treat.

Comment: @dvdfrddsgn That might work but I don't think that is valid based on the `user-scalable` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)

Answer (score 48):

This worked for me in all android browsers:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

A common mistake is that people use 2 meta viewport tags like this:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

The second meta viewport tag overrides the first one in some browsers (for example - chrome for android).
There is no reason to have two meta viewport tags, as the second one is contained within the first one.

See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers/12270403) for more details

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all of them but not work for me. And I found this one really work.

```
     <!-- set viewport to native resolution (android) - disable zoom !-->
   <meta 
       name="viewport" 
       content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" 
    />
```

from http://andidittrich.de/index.php/2012/02/disable-zoom-function-of-android-browser-force-native-resolution/

Comment: I had the same problem and this is the only working solution for: android browser, chrome and iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
```

Meta Viewport tag does solve the problem in most of the cases. But Android has a strange issue where on orientation change the meta tag is reset and you can scale or zoom the page again.

For fixing this issue in Android monitor orientaionchange and set meta viewport tag on every orientationchange event.

Here is the link with code snippet http://moduscreate.com/orientation-change-zoom-scale-android-bug/

Answer (score -1):

"user-scalable=no" has never worked for me, instead I use "user-scalable=0" which seems to work a treat.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I can still zoom in with that setting. Seems like Android (2.2) simply cannot do it.

Answer (score -2):

Use below lines of Code :

Check the application Samsung Galaxy S there it is supporting. But when I am opening the same link inside the Galaxy Ace there Turn Off the Zooming is not supporting.

Please Check your application some Other mobile and check. Please go through below link you will get the Idea:

http://garrows.com/?p=337

Answer (score -4):

Try all of this at the same time (extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page/4472910#4472910)):

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Then tell us your experience

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Stackoverflow notifications have worked better in the past. Your suggested code doesn't change anything at all. I can still zoom the page.