# How to disable zoom in Chrome on Android?

Tags: android, html, ios, google-chrome, safari

trying to prevent zooming on a page in Chrome on Android, and it doesn't want to behave.  I'm using the code below, which works fine on the stock Android browser and Safari on iOS.  Any thoughts?

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;' name='viewport' />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Your second meta viewport tag overrides the first one.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers/12270403

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding `minimum-scale=1` to your `viewport` meta tag - if that doesn't help, it's likely that disabling zoom isn't supported by Chrome for Android (HTC's proprietary browser intentionally doesn't allow you to disable zoom, for instance)

Update: I just checked, and it looks like Chrome *does* support disabling zoom, but you have two viewport tags in your code? The second one is likely overriding the first. Remove the second one.

See this list of [mobile browser support for disabling zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270403/1658527) for details and a good suggestion for disabling zoom across multiple browsers.

Comment: actually it worked,  I posted previous comment prematurely, since edited. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 13):

I'm using the belt and braces approach, configuring all viewport settings available, as per [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/)'s [Targeting Screens from Web Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html)

> The following syntax shows all of the supported viewport properties and the general types of values accepted by each one:

```
<meta name="viewport"
  content="
    height = [pixel_value | device-height] ,
    width = [pixel_value | device-width ] ,
    initial-scale = float_value ,
    minimum-scale = float_value ,
    maximum-scale = float_value ,
    user-scalable = [yes | no] ,
    target-densitydpi = [dpi_value | 
     device-dpi | high-dpi | medium-dpi | low-dpi]
    " />
```

**The configured meta tag for no zoom:**

```
<meta name="viewport"
  content="
    height = device-height,
    width = device-width,
    initial-scale = 1.0,
    minimum-scale = 1.0,
    maximum-scale = 1.0,
    user-scalable = no,
    target-densitydpi = device-dpi
    " />
```

**And as a one liner:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```