# How to stop zoom on webpage?

Tags: android, html, css

I am creating a android web application.
Can I anyhow disable the zoom functionality on the webpage ?
In others words I want it could not be resized.
help

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322364/how-to-disable-zoom-in-chrome-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if it helps :

```
<head>  
  <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0,   user-scalable=no" />  
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 zoom_controll.getZoomControls().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `meta` tag section of your HTML use `minimum-scale=1` to set your viewport.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />`

[Click here is for thorough explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers/12270403#12270403)

How ever i must add that part of that functionality depends on the device's native functionality