# Viewport meta for android default browser

Tags: android, viewport

I'm trying to display an image (320x480px) in a webpage on android.
I'm trying to configure the viewport meta cause I want the image displayed in full screen.

Actually I simply configured the viewport like that

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px" />
```

and it's working perfectly, except with the android default browser. I tried Chrome, Opera and Firefox, and they all display the image correctly.

Regarding this post [Full webpage and disabled zoom viewport meta tag for all mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers) I tried to configure it in this way without success :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=yes" />
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=320,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=yes" />
```

Do you have any idea on how to configure the viewport correctly  ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

**user-scalable** - controls wither the user can "pinch-to-zoom".

**width** - the width of the viewport.

**All of the attributes require integer values, NOT floating point values.**

**In other words, 1 and not 1.0. Or you could use percentage.**

There is no point in setting min and max scaling attributes to the same value.
Also, initial-scale is known to cause problems in iOS if set to 1.

Comment: According to android documentation it is a float and not an integer: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Viewport

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below one. It works perfectly for me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 0):

I like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=321; user-scalable=no;" />
```

Android only accepts viewport widths GREATER than 320, so setting it on 321 did the trick for me.