# meta name="viewport" doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have that meta tag in my website www.ssd-vergleichen.de

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;"/>
```

To prevent the device from initial zooming into the website.
When watching the website on my chrome mobile browser on Samsung Galaxy S2, the website is beeing zoomed in about 400%. 
What did I do wrong? Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Edit: With using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

it works in Android's standard webbrowser, but still not in Chrome. I wonder if it works in IOS?

Edit2: No, it also doesn't work with iOS http://iphonetester.com/

[image]

Comment: Checkout the browser tests at http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/ There are details of which devices correctly implement each part of the meta tag.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=320, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">
```

As I understand it `width="device-width"` constrains the width of the layout to the device width. Surely setting `intial-scale=1` is then telling the browser to zoom 100% (i.e. not scaled)?

**Update**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1;"/>
```

Is intended to be used to scale responsive sites correctly.  Considering your site is fixed to a width of 1100px, setting `initial-scale=1` will not result in the whole page being visible.

From the W3C [Use Meta Viewport Element To Identify Desired Screen Size](http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/#bp-viewport)

Comment: this doesn't work too. And `initial-scale=1` means that the website is not zoomed at all. What you mean is 200% or `initial-scale=2` I think

Comment: Sorry by zoom 100% I mean showing the web page at it's intended size. i.e. no scaling, which it appears to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

with no `;`

Comment: it seems to work for the Android standard browser, but not for Chrome (watch my edit)

Comment: I use the above code on my site and it works no problem in Chrome, so something might be interfering with it. I'll check your site...

Comment: I've already cleared my chrome cache. Still having that issue.. It seems like it's not working on iPhone, too: http://iphonetester.com/

Comment: Does this help at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers/12270403#12270403

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I was able to fix it by toying with the target-densitydpi attribute and setting it to high while setting the width to device-width

Like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.8, zoom=10%, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=high-dpi">
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
```

In CSS put this:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should write

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="[your_content_params]" />
```

I tried this and it worked.