# meta name="viewport" doesn't seem to have effect

Tags: html, web, responsive-design, webkit

I've placed this tag on [my website](http://litvin.co.nf/viewport_index.html):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And on Firefox and Chrome for Android the site looks like this:

[image]

While I'm expecting it to look like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234649/meta-name-viewport-doesnt-work-as-expected), but nothing helped.

Comment: What are the device widths on those cases?

Answer (score 0):

This tells the browser to render the page at the same width as the device's screen has pixels:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

It sounds like you'd prefer to render at some other width, like maybe 800px:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=800, initial-scale=1.0" />
```