# About Maximum-scale on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, hash

Double tab ignore maximum-scale=1.0 on HTC evo4g.

I used below meta tag,

```
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport>
```

But whenever I double tab on the page, it comes bigger. after that I can zoom in, out.

Comment: If you have 3 separate questions then post 3 separate question posts. Though I would probably vote to close question 1 and 2 as they stand. Might let you get away with 3

Comment: Could you introduce to me the link about 'hash tag' and 'button'? then I'm very appreciate that :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers/12270403#12270403

Answer (score 1):

There are many browser specific intricacies when it comes to disabling zoom. I've answered a question on this before highlighting the specific settings on different versions of browsers to disable the zoom: [Full webpage and disabled zoom viewport meta tag for all mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers/12270403#12270403)