# How to set up HTML meta vievport to start alike on every mobile device?

Tags: android, html, css

I have a website, what has 1000px width on desktop computers. I want to show it 100% width on every mobile device.

I was tried this code, but failed on Android 2.2.x :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I use this doctype code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

**Edited:** I tried this code too, this is irrelevant parameter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I want to see full width of my page on every mobile device in every viewport (landscape and portrait too).

What will be the solution?

Comment: Have you used media-queries in your CSS files?

Comment: No, only this codes used.

Comment: You need to also use media-queries along with this code on your CSS. - @netdjw

Comment: It is necessary to write different CSS code? There is no way use only HTML meta tags?

Comment: No. Media queries adds responsiveness to your website and can display elements accordingly to your size with the provided meta code. - @netdjw

Comment: The base of the problem is this: if I see the page in landscape that is absolutely correct. But if I change to portrait view the browser don't resize to 100% the page. How can I define to portrait view default scale? Or how can I find out what is the user viewport? I want to define default scale on landscape AND on portrait too.

Comment: Have you tried using `<!doctype html>` as your doctype? - @netdjw

Comment: @Nathan Lee: yep, that is irrelevant parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Devices lower than Android 2.3 do not support the viewport-meta-tag.

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270403/995320