# How to disable zoom in aosp browers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, android-source

So basically, I'm developing a mobile website with fixed page dimensions.
Using this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

doesn't help. I still can double-tap and pinch to zoom on older AOSP browsers (4.0 - 4.2.2).
Does anyone have a solution for this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/) source:

> Except for Android WebKit. Obviously. Android WebKit allows initial-scale to set the layout viewport width only if the value is 1 AND there is no width directive. So only initial-scale=1 without any other directives works.

Comment: I'm sure, I've tried it already, but I'll give it another shot next week, when I'll get the 4.0.1 phone. Meanwhile, on 4.2+ aosp browser and any webkit one, everything works perfectly with the "device-width".