# Select - Zoom on iPhone

Tags: html, css, html-select

When I view my website with an iPhone 5 and use select menu screen is zoom.

I used:

- `minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0` and it helps, but not for 100%
- `webkit-touch-callout: none;`
- `-webkit-user-select: none;`

both css not help.

Comment: have you add the meta tag?

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345896/full-webpage-and-disabled-zoom-viewport-meta-tag-for-all-mobile-browsers

Comment: and I looked on this link but not help ... maybe it is not zoom now, but when I click on select page is align to left (like padding-right for body)