# Cordova scaling not respecting meta

Tags: cordova

I'm using this meta to prevent scaling

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

I've tested it on Android 10 on a phone that had scaling 1.5x and the app was scaled. What is the proper way to prevent scaling ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in Android browsers: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36922308

But maybe this will give you some clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270403/3852382

Comment: Status: Won't Fix (Obsolete) ? Every answer is from 2013?

Comment: Otherwise, I can only advise you to make sure that you have only one viewport meta tag.