# Auto Zoom on text field using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap.css so my site is responsive. On the top right corner I have a `<input type="text">` field. When I am using my Android phone, I found this issue:
1) I click on the text field
2) It automatically zooms the input field
3) Bootstrap realizes that a zoom has occurred, and shows on the screen the top-left corner, so that I cannot see the search field anymore (top right corner)

Is there a way to:
1) Prevent 3) when auto zoom occurrs?
2) If not, disable auto zoom?

Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap is not doing that zooming this has nothing to do with Bootstrap. Long time problem. Read up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073396/disable-zoom-on-input-focus-in-android-webpage

Answer (score 2):

If your website is properly designed for a mobile device you could decide not allow scaling. Add this into your for mobile devices. Then do your widths in percentages and you'll be fine:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```