# @media query doesnt work with forms

Tags: css, media-queries

I am used the @media query to create a responsive website. When I am viewing the page it responds nicely to all devices. However, when viewing on a mobile phone, whenever a form field is selected it appears the device ignores at @media specifications that I have. It doesn't happen with tablets or desktops only mobile phones, and it only happens when the form field is clicked.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:200px) and (max-width:720px) and (orientation:landscape){}
```

I am using this as well in my html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: You could take a look at this? Not sure if this is the same problem as what you're facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone

Comment: maybe try only applying `<meta content='initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width' name='viewport'>` without all the extra options. Might be that the mobile browser can't read all those properties. Just a guess here