# Text field not auto zoom on focus [JQuery/Javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I made a form in web app with some fields. In IOs Safari it should be zoom (i think) when user tap in it. Like in this picture

[image]

But my problem is that when i tab on it nothing happens like zoom. Only virtual keyboard is open. I also want to zoom.

I am using `JQuery Mobile 1.4` and this is the code for `input field`

```
<label for="fname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" placeholder="First Name" onKeyPress="restoreState(this)"/>
```

following is my view picture but it is not zoom when user tab (Iphone Safari)
[image]

**Update**
Following `ViewPorts` i tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

                                  OR

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

Comment: try with onkeyup..@blu

Comment: I think something is wrong with `meta viewport`

Comment: @MindaugasVečkys i checked different values in `viewport` but nothing changes.

Comment: @SmartKiller onKeyUp? should i do some custom code for that? because am thinking its some feature in iphone/android?

Comment: @BluAngel is there such feature in iOS? So if i'm viewing a webpage and clicking a textfield, the whole thing zooms into the textfield..? I've seen the keyboard pushing things up, but haven't seen this before.

Comment: `user-scalable=1` is wrong, it should be `user-scalable=yes` .. have you tried that?

Comment: @TilwinJoy There are alot question like that   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone  that is why i am thinking it is some feature in these devices

Comment: @urbz yes i also tried with `yes` but didn't happened anything

Comment: Remove from `css` `input:focus` and `font-size`

Comment: @MindaugasVečkys remove those from `JQuery Mobile` `css` file?

Comment: @BluAngel from all `css`. It privents from zooming [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

Jquery to do this

```
function AllowZoom(flag) {
  if (flag == true) {
    $('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
    $('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10.0, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=1" />');
  } else {
    $('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
    $('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />');              
  }
}
```

Use `user-scalable=0` //zoomDisable

Use `user-scalable=1` //zoomEnable

**Updated:**

**initial-scale**   (0 to 10.0) Multiplier that sets the scale of the page after its initial display. Safe bet: if you need to set it, set it to 1.0. Larger values = zoomed in, smaller values = zoomed out

**minimum-scale**   (0 to 10.0) The minimum multiplier the user can “zoom out” to. Defaults to 0.25 on mobile Safari.

**maximum-scale**   (0 to 10.0) The minimum multiplier the user can “zoom in” to. Defaults to 1.6 on mobile Safari.

Comment: is this value `maximum-scale=10.0` can be greater? i tried `20.0` but it give same zoom? i need some more

Comment: minimum-scale=1.0
This parameter tells Safari that a user should only be allowed to zoom out to the actual width of the web page. So if the web page is 320 pixels wide a user will only be able to zoom out to 320pixels.

maximum-scale=10.0
This parameter tells Safari to allow a user to scale to 10 times the size of the site.

Comment: i think you also need to use this for the width of the device : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: Thanks :) its much helpful now.

Comment: I tried ur solution with something like that  
`$(document).on('click',function(e){
  if( $(e.target).is('input:text') ) {
   AllowZoom(true);
  } else {
   AllowZoom(false);
  }
 });`

  So when i click on fields that are type of text my pages zooms in but when i click outside that fields it didn't zoomout to normal page. Any thoughts how can i achieve that functionality

Comment: also if i select input of some other type after zoomin it back to normal state but not when i tap in some empty place on page it didn't zoom out that is so annoying :/