# Mobile inputs — zoom on entry but don't zoom back out when "Done"

Tags: ios, input, zooming

When you click to enter text in an input in iOS, it zooms in (which is fine) but is there a way to make it zoom back out when you hit 'Done'?

Comment: I think this is that you want... http://stackoverflow.com/q/2989263/3802688