# Why doesn't mobile html input zoom back out when done?

Tags: android, html, css, ios, zooming

This might well be a duplicate of [this 8 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796393/mobile-inputs-zoom-on-entry-but-dont-zoom-back-out-when-done), but there are no answers there and the only comment links to a related, but irrelevant question about how to prevent the zoom-in altogether.

[Here is a bare-bones web page](https://sidewayss.com/test/input.html) on my personal site that I have used to verify (using browserstack) that this happens on all recent mobile platforms and browsers. So this would appear to be by design. Open the page in a browser on a mobile device and tap the tiny (1rem font size) numeric input field. The numeric keypad appears and the `visualViewport.scale` increases, zooming in on the field. That's cool, no problem there. The problem is that when you're done inputting a new number, the screen stays zoomed in.

Is there any way to get it to zoom back out upon closing the keypad? I realize that the user can do it manually with a pinch gesture, but it sure seems that it's something that should happen automatically. The zoom-in was automatic, so why doesn't it zoom back out when you're done?

I'm a programmer, not a web designer, and I'm currently building test/demo pages for a project. So please excuse my overall ignorance of responsive web design and mobile web design in particular. I notice that if I increase the font size of the input, then the zoom-in doesn't happen, so the problem goes away. But I've already got a couple of pages looking pretty good across devices, even handling rotating the device, so I don't want to mess with my font-sizes unless I have to. I'm already using `rem` and `em` units for fonts, no `px` units. The fonts on my actual pages appear larger on mobile screens than my bare-bones example page link above, so they are very legible. I'm not familiar with the `viewport` meta tag either, and my experiments with it have not panned out.

EDIT: further testing yields the following results:

1. To avoid the zoom-in everywhere ...my pages' font size must be a minimum of 35px, approximately 2.2rem @16px. iOS requires the largest minimum size (on both Safari and Chrome).
2. ...or the viewport min-scale value must be at least 0.9 (again iOS requires the highest value, Android Chrome gets by with 0.55). My pages' font-size is set to 1.1025rem, 17.64px, which is probably why this value is 0.9 and not 1.0 - I used my actual pages for testing, not the bare-bones page I linked to above:

`<meta name="viewport" content="min-scale=0.9"/>`

3. Only in Chrome on Android, this setting prevents the zoom-in:

`<meta name="viewport" content="interactive-widget=overlays-content"/>`

The minimum font-size and scale values require big changes to my current layout to adapt. 35px strikes me as a very large minimum font size. Since there is clearly no way to auto-zoom-out after the keypad hides, avoiding the zoom-in appears to be the only way to avoid this clumsy UI behavior.

Comment: This is all browser specific.  It does not happen universally.  It's not a behavior of the OS, it's a behavior of the browser app.  And at least on Android it would be difficult to impossible to fix, because the application isn't notified when the soft keyboard is closed.

Comment: @GabeSechan - I realize it's not a behavior of the OS.  I didn't say it was.  But browsers can behave differently on different OSes. I have reproduced this on Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari, Samsung, and UC, on both Android and iOS. That's every combination available on browserstack, and as close to "universal" as I can get. Do you know of an exception?  There is no browser event for opening or closing the keypad, but the `resize` event on the `window` object does fire. But even then, there is no programmatic way to set the zoom level, `visualViewport` is read-only.

Comment: I can say I use ANdroid Firefox daily. and it does NOT zoom in when you tap on a field.  I've never seen that behavior in Chrome either.  It does do a relayout, but it's no visually bigger.

Comment: @GabeSechan - that's probably because the pages you are using have font-sizes that are bigger. I mention that specifically in my question.  There is some limit on that, and it does vary by device/browser.  In the example I linked to with `font-size:1rem`, it reproduces 100% on those platforms. If I bump the font-size up to `2rem` it *fails* to reproduce on 90% of platforms.  At `2.5rem` I was able to get it to fail 100%. This can also be avoided by setting the `viewport` meta tag so that the scale defaults to `1`.  In my cases `visualViewport.scale` is defaulting to somewhere below `0.5`.