# Disable resizing on a specific div when window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an application that contains a main screen and an edition popup. Both are `div`s, with the popup `div` having a bigger `z-index`, and covering the whole screen :

```
<div id="my-main-screen">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
<div id="my-popup" style="z-index: 1; width: 100%; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

My problem is the following :

- On mobile, focusing in and out of text fields in my popup shows and hides the virtual keyboard, which triggers a `window`'s `resize` event.
- **Resizing also resizes the main screen `div`**, which is useless and slow, because my main screen is rather complex
- **The result is that focusing in and out of text fields in my popup `div` feel slow and irresponsive.**

I tried hiding the main screen div. It works when in the popup... but then when I close the popup I have to make the main screen visible again, and that is as slow as resizing.

**Is there a way to disable resizing on just the main screen `div`, without hiding it ?**

Comment: I have not tried this myself but I think you should try what they are describing in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone

Comment: @Kamelkent the question you're referring to is about auto-zooming. Mine is about the window being resized to make room for the virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but you may try to set maximum scale to 1 in your  viewport tag to make your document not to scale on mobile devices...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: The popup *has* to resize.