# White space outside html on mobile Safari when keyboard is open

Tags: css, mobile-safari, browserstack

I have a very weird bug in my JavaScript library on mobile Safari, that I've tried to reproduce with a simple example:

I have basic css and html:

```css
html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* mobile viewport bug fix */
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
#term {
    background: black;
    color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

*html*:

```html
    ...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="term" contenteditable>
    <h1>HELLO Mobile</h1>
    ...
```

and when I open the website on mobile Safari and open the virtual keyboard, I can scroll down outside of the content.

Here is the screenshot from BrowserStack when I hover over body, I'm not able to hover over html to highlight it.

[image: Mobile Safari]

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? It looks like a basic page.

Here is the link to the website: https://terminal.jcubic.pl/mobile.html

As you can see from the code I've tried to fix the issue by adding:

```
-webkit-fill-available
```

Found in an article: [CSS fix for 100vh in mobile WebKit](https://css-tricks.com/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/) by Chris Coyier. But it doesn't make any change.

Is there a way to get rid of that white space, it seems that even CodePen has this issue. Is it a bug in Mobile Safari, is there a hack to fix it?

**EDIT**:

I think that this is a long-standing issue and Apple doesn't care how miserable users and developers are. [Safari on iOS scrolls beyond  element when virtual keyboard is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52857694/387194)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. no, it doesn't answer my question. I have this only on Safari, it works fine on Android, also it happens when a virtual keyboard is opened, not when address bar is hidden.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JJT no, I think that will start a bounty maybe someone will reply.

Comment: I found a solution using `react-div-100vh` for react

Comment: @JJT this has nothing to do with React, that is just JavaScript library. The real solution if you found it is in CSS.

Comment: I think this is just normal Ios behavior, looked at popular sites and didn't find any which I couldn't "overscroll" outside content. But thought about it aswell before and a hack would be great

Comment: I think that this is a long-lasting issue and Apple doesn't care how miserable users and developers are. [Safari on iOS scrolls beyond <html> element when virtual keyboard is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52857694/387194)

Comment: Have you filed or upvoted on the bug at Safari/webkit? I don't think this is fixable unless you had Javascript scroll detection that if the top of the #term was out of view then to add some `#term:focus` CSS values that incrementally pushed this div down 3rem each time the user scrolled and then when then the user got to within a certain distance of the top of #term when scrolling upwards this CSS is removed. Not worth the effort IMHO. You should post the webkit bug status on here and we can all upvote.

Comment: @TheChewy it is an issue that has been on for ages. But I have no idea how to report it since I was told on Twitter that it's only for Safari and other WebKit-based browsers work fine. I've sent a tweet to Jen Simmons, but I don't know if they saw my reply it was tweeted few days after I've repled (found a link in the newsletter that didn't read immediately) https://twitter.com/jensimmons/status/1491064075987873792

Comment: seems this is a long-standing Safari bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996535/how-to-fix-safaris-html-margin-bottom-bug-in-ios-10-3-1

Comment: @mb21 thanks there are some interesting and promising answers.

Comment: Anyone ever find a solution to this?? Insane this has been an issue for years...

Comment: @NateBabbel this is a bug in Safari and Apple developers need to fix this. But they don't have time because they need to implement every new feature from different specs that no one needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS File:

```
const appHeight = () => {
 const doc = document.documentElement
 doc.style.setProperty('--app-height', `${window.innerHeight}px`)
}
window.addEventListener('resize', appHeight)
appHeight()
```

CSS File:

```
:root {
 --app-height: 100%;
}
html,
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 height: var(--app-height);
}
```

It may help

Comment: It doesn't work. It's even worse. Because the page jumps https://terminal.jcubic.pl/mobile_fix.html I don't think that this can be fixed that easily.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried:

```css
body {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: But you know that "auto", when there is a default width of 100%, will make no difference than with `margin: 0`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've checked.