# Empty space on the bottom of the page when swipe up on safari ios

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I have a web page that occupy all the viewport of the browser. When I focus on a input the keyboard opens and if I swipe up the web page there is an extra empty space on the bottom even after the bouce effect. This only occurs on safari ios. Android browsers devices seem fine.

I tried to adding

```
html, body, .main-container {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

But no success. It seems that an extra scroll bar is appended to global page.

We can see a similar "issue" in wikipedia.org main page. If you focus on the search input and scroll to the bottom (still with the focus on the search input) and then swipe up you can see an extra empty space was created under the last link - "Privacy Policy"

Once you close the keyboard the empty space is vanished.

Does anyone know how to solve this little (but annoying) bug?

Thanks

P.S.: I am on windows so it's not so easy to debug

Comment: seems this is a long-standing Safari bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996535/how-to-fix-safaris-html-margin-bottom-bug-in-ios-10-3-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal in safari browser. try to open any web page and scroll up you will see the extra white space at the bottom of the page. once you up your hand from the screen everything will return as default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to find any safari / iOS documentation about this, didn't find any. Do you know if there is any documentation refering this?

Comment: you're welcome. 
Nope. I already searched a lot for this before, I did not find any solution for it. and it's something normal in safari browser. do not care about sir.

Comment: apple needs to fix this, it's terrible.