# iOS Safari: redundant bottom whitespace color bug

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, background-color

While debugging another iOS issue I stumbled upon something which seems to be a pretty weird iOS Safari bug.

- Source code: https://github.com/Maximaximum/ios-safari-bottom-white-space
- Demo: https://maximaximum.github.io/ios-safari-bottom-white-space/

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the demo page in iOS Safari
2. Click the input to open the virtual keyboard
3. Scroll the page to the very bottom
4. Observe the whitespace block at the bottom of the page

I'm able to reproduce the issue on iOS 16.4.1 (iPhone 13).

The questions I'm trying to find answers for are:

1. **Why** is there a redundant whitespace at the page bottom?
2. Why is the redundant whitespace block **WHITE exclusively on iOS Safari**, not on other browsers? Not even on iOS Chrome
3. What determines **the height** of the white bottom whitespace block?
4. Why, if I replace line 8 in `style.css` with **`body {background-color: yellow}`**, the whitespace block becomes **transparent**, but if I replace it with body **`{background-color: #fefefe}`**, it is still **white**?
5. Why, if I replace line 17 with **`min-height: 25px;`**, the bottom whitespace block becomes **transparent**?

Any ideas appreicated.

Comment: Additional investigation reveals that the color of the bottom block is related to the iOS Safari Tinting feature. When tinting is disabled in Safari settings, the bottom block color becomes transparent

Comment: This is still occurring on iOS 17.2.1

Comment: Same issue mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996535/how-to-fix-safaris-html-margin-bottom-bug-in-ios-10-3-1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757554/unwanted-padding-at-bottom-of-page-when-input-focussed-on-mobile-safari. Neither have accepted/working solutions

Comment: It seems that you have edited the file because now it is just a div and an input, and when I click on it nothing popup and the background is white not yellow.