# Return to original zoom scale after auto-zoom

Tags: iphone, out

I have a mobile site which zooms in on drop downs, when they receive focus on an iPhone, because the font size is less that 16px. That has been covered here:

[Disable Auto Zoom in Input "Text" tag - Safari on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone/46254706#46254706)

... Zooming is fine, however, when the iPhone has zoomed in after focusing on a drop down, it stays zoomed in. It would be totally fine if it zoomed back out again when I move to the next control or select a value. As it stays zoomed in, the form no longer fits on the screen.

I'm guessing the zooming-back-out could be done in JavaScript, but is there an iPhone-specific setting that will instruct it to auto-zoom-out?

Ideally this won't affect Android devices, unless they have similar issues.

Comment: The correct answer for this I've found is to design the form correctly to be mobile friendly more, and not have small fonts. It required some simplification and a clean design.