# Html Input Text covered by Mobile keyboards (Android - Ios)

Tags: javascript, html, css

i can't fix this error, when i open keyboard on my website (mobile), input text ( at the bottom of the page ) is totally covered or rezised, this is my code :

HTML:

```css
.text-user{
    height: 190px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#ebe6d8;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#messageBox {
    
    display: block; 
    width: 230px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0;
    outline: none;
    position:fixed;
    left: 180;
    right: 250; 
}
```

```html
<div class="Main" id="main">
<div id="messages">
x
</div>


    <input type="text" id="messageBox" maxlength="100" placeholder="Digita qui il tuo Messaggio"/>
         <button id="send" onclick="Invio()"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>

</div>
```

the problematic field is

```
<input type="text" id="messageBox" maxlength="100" placeholder="Digita qui il tuo Messaggio"/>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Auto Zoom in Input "Text" tag - Safari on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone)

Comment: I need to fix this error, keyboard mobile cover my input text, i want to avoid this, textbox must be over the keyboard at the top, the user should be able to see what he write

Comment: Could you check your snippet and make sure that the input element is actually at the bottom of the page as it is near the top when I try it. Also, where do want the button to be, at the moment it is covered partially by the input element.

Comment: the button actually it's not important, i need to fix this error, i have my input field into the main div, which contains the div of messages and input textfield