# React: trigger a zoom out after a zoom in caused by input focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile

There is a way to zoom out a page in React after the page was zoomed-in because an `<input>` got focused? Imagine a simple component like the following: I'd like to zoom out on form submit.

```
const Component = (props) =>{

 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   //Zoom out
 }

 return(
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input/>
      <button>Sign in</button>
   </form>
 );
}
```

**Important:**

I do **NOT** want to disable the zoom-in effect. I found that by setting viewport `maximum-scale=1` or by setting font-size to 16px I can disable it [[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone?noredirect=1&lq=1)], but that's not the behaviour I want for my page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap the contents in a div and use its ref to zoom.

```
const Layout: React.FC<props> = ({ pageHeader }) => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    wrapperRef.current.style.zoom = "90%";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef} style={{ width: "100%"}}>
      {/* rest of content here */}
    </div>);
}
```

I am not sure if it is the best way but I had the same issue, this works for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger this inside your handleSubmit() method to reset the zoom to 100%:

```
window.document.body.style.zoom = 1;
```

Note that this will not work in Firefox according to caniuse:
https://caniuse.com/css-zoom

Comment: I'm working with typescript and zoom can't be found among the styles belonging to `body`. Here is the error I get: `Property 'zoom' does not exist on type 'CSSStyleDeclaration'`.