# React.js. : How to disable zoom in on mobile web?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Mui Textfield and every time when i click on it, a zoom to that field occurs.
I know this kind of question has been asked before, but seems that after trying all sort of options offered in the past no one of those options solved the issue.So is there a way to disable a zoom in on mobile web at all?

Comment: did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone)

Comment: if the font-size is less than 16px, screen will be zoomed. So, you can increase the font-size if adding `maximum-scale=1` did not help

Comment: @iamhuynq yes I tried it before and it did not help at all,

Comment: @Alijonov I increased the font then 16px and higher, and still nothing.

Answer (score 5):

you can try to put this meta tag on the html head or `public/index.html` (if you use create-react-app library and want to apply the setting to all pages):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

you can see more solution in this [link](https://w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page-using-html-and-css.html) incase this alternative wont work for you

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the succinct, up-to-date, answer.  This worked perfectly for me for a React app using Vite.