# Website on iOS (Chrome and Safari) too wide

Tags: css, ios, google-chrome, browser, safari

I am developing a site which is to also run on mobile devices. I have an issue with both Chrome and Safari on my iPhone 13 Pro Max, iOS 16.2.

The problem is that when I launch my dialog to log in, the content appears to "grow" horizontally, causing what appears to be a "zoom". I have checked every CSS element in my app, and I cannot see anywhere I'm specifying a `min-width` or anything of that sort that might cause this. Can someone help me pinpoint the issue? Or point me to a resource that can help alleviate this problem?

My site is live here: https://chonk.jambudipa.io

Here is how it looks when you launch the dialog by clicking on "Sign in":

[image: Before]

And here is how it looks after pinching to resize the window to fix the size issue, how it should look:

[image: After]

What is going on?? I have tried all sort of meta properties and strange CSS hacks found online, but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Works perfectly!