# How to disable mobile input auto zoom like some websites and Stack Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

On iPhone if text input's font-size is less than 16px, it automatically zooms in. I didn't wanted to add since its not recommended, but tried the meta `viewport` hacks, but it didn't worked too, here is my viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

But I've saw many websites that has input less than 16px and it doesn't zoom in to input on my mobile, even without `viewport` values `user-scalable=no` or `maximum-scale=1` and one of that websites is Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow example here with 13px input size and doesn't has particular viewports tags that every post on internet says its needed to disable input zoom in.

[image]

Is there some knowledge that passess in secret to disable this zoom? I've checked many articles but all of them is limited to what I tried/mentioned above. I'm guessing there might be a JavaScript hack for this but my attempts of `preventDefault` on focus, click etc. failed.

Comment: Have you checked all the options from answers on this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone

Comment: I just find out that Next.js was adding a second meta viewport that nullifies my viewport (facepalm here) its worse than forgetting semi-column, its not possible to forget with recent editors tho. Next.js and their new features got me spending hell of a time for the second time in this project. Thanks for the link but looks like I was my worst enemy all along(deep~)

Comment: Still I've solved it with adding `user-scalable=no` to viewport, which Stack Overflow doesn't seem to add, wonder how they solved it.