# Disable auto zoom/field zoom on input tags on my Mobile Site - WITHOUT disabling all zoom capabilities

Tags: jquery, html, input, zooming

I have spent all day looking for a solution, and this site keeps coming up, SO why not ask you guys.

I an building our companies mobile website and we want to disable the auto zoom mobile devices use to zoom into text/search/email inputs when they are focused on. 
I am building the site in HTML5 and have seen/tested the 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />`
solution. With various properties (ie. minimum-scale=*#, maximum-scale=*#" )
This, works in almost ALL mobile devices I am testing on. Only one problem. I want the user to be able to zoom in/out at their leisure. (we have some higher res product shots that would be nice to see up close)

How can I disable zooming in when clicking on input tags, while retaining full manual user zoom control?

p.s the site also uses jQuery. So any thoughts using that might help.

thank you
Jrak

Answer (score 29):

Setting the meta tag in the `<head>` like this worked for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: User can force zoom in mobile chrome options, in which case this doesn't do anything..

Comment: This does solve the auto-zoom when text inputs are focused, but does not allow zooming into a picture. The whole site cannot be zoomed.

Comment: This will break devices zooming ability

Answer (score 15):

It may not work exactly for your styling, but if you set the font-size of input elements to be 16px or above, the onfocus zooming will stop.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

See: [Disable Auto Zoom in Input "Text" tag - Safari on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone/5196750#5196750)

There's no clean way I could find, but here's a hack...

1) I noticed that the mouseover event happens prior to the zoom, but the zoom happens before mousedown or focus events.

2) You can dynamically change the META viewport tag using javascript (see [Enable/disable zoom on iPhone safari with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750028/enable-disable-zoom-on-iphone-safari-with-javascript/3357148#3357148))

So, try this (shown in jquery for compactness):

```
$("input[type=text], textarea").mouseover(zoomDisable).mousedown(zoomEnable);
function zoomDisable(){
  $('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
  $('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0" />');
}
function zoomEnable(){
  $('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
  $('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1" />');
}
```

This is definitely a hack... there may be situations where mouseover/down don't always catch entries/exits, but it worked well in my tests and is a solid start.

Comment: Doesn't work on Android, I'm afraid. Also, won't using mouseover to catch focuses on inputs fail even on iOS if the user selects the next input in a form via the 'Next' button on the keyboard? (I assume iOS has this feature?)

Answer (score 6):

It took me a while to find it but here's the best code that I found......http://nerd.vasilis.nl/prevent-ios-from-zooming-onfocus/

```
var $viewportMeta = $('meta[name="viewport"]');
$('input, select, textarea').bind('focus blur', function(event) {
$viewportMeta.attr('content', 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=' +        (event.type == 'blur' ? 10 : 1));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

a very simple hack is to set:

```
input, textarea {font-size:16px;}
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it sets the selected elements' font to default by iPhone & stops the input fields to zoom for fitting the screen.

Answer (score -1):

If you set a webkit transform to any value other than 1 (or 1.0) 
then auto-zoom on selecting an input tag is disabled on iPhone.

```
document.body.style.webkitTransformOrigin= "0% 0%";
document.body.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1.1)";
```

I haven't tested other mobile browsers.