# Keeping page at original size after selecting input text on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mobile

On mobile, when you select an input box, it enlarges the input box, and the rest of the page to where the input box filled up to almost the whole screen. After you press enter, and after it calls and completes the ajax call, the page stays enlarge so the only thing you can see is the input box.

Is there a way to keep the screen at its original size, even when the input box is selected? Thanks.

```
<input type = "text">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5111964/2518525