# about modal in mobile device

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

My problem is that when I clicked on link there will be opened one modal. I will type my feedback in that modal for that keyboard is opened because of opened keyboard message text area is no scrolled on top.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? What is the expected behaviour? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: are you looking for something like this [Disable auto zoom/field zoom on input tags on my Mobile Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111964/disable-auto-zoom-field-zoom-on-input-tags-on-my-mobile-site-without-disabling)

Comment: No @Syed Ali. I can't expalin my question .Thanks Syed Ali and urbz

Comment: You will check how login is worked in gmail in mobile device i want this type of facility in my modal.         Can you give me your email-id? So that I can give screenshot ?If there is no problem...

Comment: please post your screenshot [here](http://pasteboard.co/) and share the link.

Comment: Thanks For guided me.                                                                                                            Urls: 
1) http://pasteboard.co/1XID8x03.png ----> My main GUI.

2) http://pasteboard.co/1XIGa70x.png ---->This is Problem.

3)http://pasteboard.co/1XIHSusf.png-->I want this type solution.                 Once again thanks.

Comment: try adding this in your `head` section `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`