# How to disable zoom in mobile responsive?

Tags: html, ios, asp.net, iphone

I have written this code for disabling zoom in or out:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

It is working fine in all mobile phones except in **recent iphones** (ex: iphone 6, iphone 7), where this function not working. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable viewport zooming iOS 10 safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it's just IOS 10 doesn't support it

You can find more [here](https://wouterdeschuyter.be/blog/how-to-disable-viewport-scaling-in-ios-10-you-dont-941140811)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to prevent it on ios 10.
First, i found an article where it says that since ios 10, the use of viewport meta is kinda ignored from safari; [here's the link](http://cloudless.studio/articles/39-safari-zoom-gesture-s-comeback-in-ios-10).

Then, that's the solution i found out as workaround:

```
$(this).on('touchmove', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.scale !== 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Notes:

- `event.preventDefault();` should works by itself without using `event.stopPropagation();`. I added it just to be sure other elements won't catch the pinch.
- I tested it on ipad and iphone, and it works good.
- I also used the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" >` for the other devices.